# Django: How to lock rows for reading?

Tags: django, database, sqlite, locking

My table contains 'Tasks' for concurrent workers. So worker should be able to 'get' task from the table, means atomically check task is exist and if exist, delete it. Other worker should be locked till this atomic process will complete. How to perform such locking in Django?

I am using code like the following, but rows are not locking for reading, two concurrent workers both enters transaction, find same task, one successfully obtain it, but second got `OperationalError('database is locked',)`

SQLite is used

```
class Task(models.Model):

    @staticmethod
    def get():
        with transaction.atomic():
            task = Task.objects.select_for_update().filter(...).first()
            if task:
                task.delete()
                return task

        return None
```

Comment: The worker with the lock error should just keep trying until the worker with the transaction lock finishes. Eventually it'll acquire the write lock and do its thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no row-level lock support in SQLite, partly because it is a file based database:

https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html

> The first step toward reading from the database file is obtaining a shared lock on the database file. A "shared" lock allows two or more database connections to read from the database file at the same time. But a shared lock prevents another database connection from writing to the database file while we are reading it.

Your best bet is to switch to a production quality database, such as [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html):

> **13.3.2. Row-level Locks**
>
> In addition to table-level locks, there are row-level locks, which are listed as below with the contexts in which they are used automatically by PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So it's not possible to lock the whole database for reading with sqlite too?

Comment: A shared lock only prevents another connection from writing, not reading. You should still be able to SELECT from it.

Answer (score 1):

So I got the point to use production-ready database, but to work with SQLite it's easy to use Redis.lock():

```
class Task(models.Model):

    @staticmethod
    def get():

        from redis import StrictRedis
        with StrictRedis().lock("some_lock_id"):

            task = Task.objects.filter(...).first()
            if task:
                task.delete()
                return task

        return None
```